# Setting random value for a Private Setter at the specific conditions

Tags: c#

I have a class with a property that has Private Setter. It's an ID and I want it to be set on the Object Creation only, and not be modifiable. 
What I have done - is I set it via specifying in the class constructor:

```
public class Customer : CustomerBase
    {
     public Customer()
        {
            CustomerId = Utilities.RandomString(6);
        }

        public Customer(string customerId)
        {
            CustomerId = customerId;
        }

        public string CustomerId { get; private set; }
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }
     }
}
```

This approach works fine for creation (and saves in CSV file correctly). 
But this seems to trigger this ID to be re-generated when I'm reading from CSV file - thus when I compare saved ID with the one I specify during Retrieve/Read - the same entry compares 2 different IDs.

Here is my Read code:

```
    public class CustomerRepository
    {
        public Customer Retrieve(string customerId)
        {
            List<Customer> records = null;
            try
            {
                using (StreamReader reader =
                    new StreamReader("DataStoreOut.csv"))
                {
                    using (CsvReader csvReader = new CsvReader(reader))
                    {
                        records = csvReader.GetRecords<Customer>().ToList();
                    }
                }
                var index = records.FindIndex(x => x.CustomerId.ToLowerInvariant() == customerId.ToLowerInvariant());
                return records[index];
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
                throw;
            }
        }
}
```

The Program class:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           var customer = new Customer();
           var customerRepository = new CustomerRepository();
           Console.WriteLine("Is it new customer (Y/N): ");
           answer = Console.ReadLine();
           if (answer == "N")
           {
             Console.WriteLine("Pls enter ID: ");
             ID = Console.ReadLine();
             customerRepository.Retrieve(ID);
           }
           else
           {
              customerRepository.Save(customer);
           }
       }
}
```

What would be a better approach to have this ID to be set-once-and-not-modifiable anymore (unless the whole row is deleted), but at the same time not getting re-generated again on every call?

Comment: I don't know how you can be getting customer objects out of the CSV when you are using csvReader.GetRecords<Animal>(). That looks like an error in your question.

Comment: Good catch. I have corrected it now in the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because when you do **csvReader.GetRecords()** it inherently calls the default constructor, which **always** creates a new random Id. This will never work properly.

So, remove the code from the constructor that assigns the random ID:

```
public class Customer : CustomerBase
{
 public Customer()
    {
        // SNIP
    }

    public Customer(string customerId)
    {
        CustomerId = customerId;
    }

    public string CustomerId { get; private set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
 }
}
```

Then assign the random ID the first time only from the calling code. Something like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       var customer = null;
       var customerRepository = new CustomerRepository();
       Console.WriteLine("Is it new customer (Y/N): ");
       answer = Console.ReadLine();
       if (answer == "N")
       {
         Console.WriteLine("Pls enter ID: ");
         ID = Console.ReadLine();
         customer = customerRepository.Retrieve(ID);
       }
       else
       {
           customer = new Customer(Utilities.RandomString(6));  // Assign random ID
           customerRepository.Save(customer);
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: You probably also need to remove that private from the setter. That will probably prevent the csvReader from setting the value properly. Why does it need to be private?

Comment: Thanks @robbpriestley, I thought that in order to make it not-modifiable (by other classes) - you need to set it as a private? And this ID - should be set only once per customer.

Comment: Well, you'll have to run the code and try it out. If you absolutely need that to be private then you may not be able to have the convenience of using the CsvReader. This seems quite academic to me. In the real world, people are not likely to care very much.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what library you are using to read the csv I would suggest you don't assign the ID in the default constructor, then always pass in an id when creating a new customer instance. The default constructor should probably be private though the CSV library might not support that.